# How to Get the Value in an HTML Tag's Attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, attr

I know the following jquery syntax will set the attribute value for src

```
$(this).closest('img.button').attr('src', '/images/button.png');
```

But how can I get or grab the 'src' attribute's value for use in my jQuery script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way, just don't provide the second parameter.

```
$(this).closest('img.button').attr('src');
```

If you provide only one parameter, `.attr(...)` acts as a **getter**.

If you provide two parameters, then `.attr(...)` acts as a **setter**.

---

If you want to remove the value, later, you would do:

```
$(this).closest('img.button').removeAttr('src');
```

Here is a link to the jQuery documentation for [`$.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: I have to wait 10 mins to select your answer as the answer so it will need to wait until I comeback to SO sometime -- I truly dislike that restriction in SO!

Comment: @H.Ferrence Please read the jQuery documentation first (http://api.jquery.com/attr/). It takes less time to refer the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

attr is getter and setter function. Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Get attribute:

```
$(this).closest('img.button').attr('src');
```

Set attribute:

```
$(this).closest('img.button').attr('src', '/images/button.png');
```

Comment: @Vega and your comment does?